# BackgroundUploader for Xamarin.Forms C#

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am working on converting my WindowsPhone project to Xamarin.Forms project.

I had a BackgroundUploader task for uploading my video files to server in background. However, I am not able to find a similar class in Xamarin Forms that does the same job.

Below is my BackgroundUploader code for WindowsPhone project.

Any kind suggestions please.

```
BackgroundUploader bguploader = new BackgroundUploader();
bguploader.SetRequestHeader(RequestHeader, jsonConverter.Serialize(Video));

UploadOperation upload = bguploader.CreateUpload(new Uri(url), videoFile);
Progress<UploadOperation> callback = new Progress<UploadOperation>(UploadProgress);
await upload.StartAsync().AsTask(canceltoken.Token, callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a **OS-specific** functionality and it has no built-in solution in Xamarin.Forms.

As you mentioned **`BackgroundUploader`** is the solution working for **UWP** and `Windows Phone`.

For some info on **iOS** background execution check out [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). You will probably use [**`NSURLSessionUploadTask`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionuploadtask).

On **Android** you should look into **Background Services**. See [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

To implement this in a cross-platform manner, you will have to create a shared interface and then provide platform-specific implementations. See [Xamarin.Forms DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Martin.
Similar to NSURLSessionUploadTask, is there any in Android Xamarin??

Comment: No, on Android in a Background service you should be ok to do any upload process you require as you are not much limited by the system. You can check out this library for example - https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service . It is a native Java library, but you can use it as inspiration for your own implementation.